# Array of pointers: std::vector<std::shared_ptr<T>>, or std::shared_ptr T[n]?

Tags: c++, arrays, concurrency, shared-ptr, skip-lists

I am implementing a concurrent skip list (based on [a listing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hF6gY.png) in [*The Art of Multiprocessor Programming*](https://www.elsevier.com/books/the-art-of-multiprocessor-programming/herlihy/978-0-12-415950-1)), and the `Node` class contains the following (Java-esque) code:

```
class Node<T> {
    ...
    final Node<T>[] next; 
    ...
    public Node(int key) {
        ...
        next = new Node[MAX_LEVEL + 1];
        ...
    }
}
```

In C++, this doesn't translate so well without raw pointers (which I desperately want to avoid, so I can use RAII). What are my options for the array of `Node`, `next`? I understand it is initialised in the constructor to a size of `MAX_LEVEL + 1`, and I'm not too sure how to do this in C++ either.

Note that the size of the array in each `Node` while not compile-time constant, is run-time constant as it isn't appended to/removed from, so I don't need the strictly *dynamic* functionality of `std::vector::emplace_back()`.

Comment: Why do you think you need `shared_ptr` at all? Also, if you are using `shared_ptr`, their overhead will dwarf any `std::vector` overhead, so there will be no reason not to use `std::vector`.

Comment: In any case, `new[]` is almost always the wrong tool! Also, `std::vector` is almost never wrong. Therefore, use that for a start and find out where it doesn't fit and why.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt, care to share *why* `new[]` is problematic? Also, after some digging, I found [this use-case](https://github.com/rhacker/concurrent-skip-list/blob/10fd0cbf35ad781dada16cea9ebea18fbb67b2d8/lib/skip_list.h#L25), very similar to mine. 

Are you suggesting that the author should have written instead: `std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Node>> next{MAX_LEVEL + 1};`, or even `std::array<std::shared_ptr<Node>, MAX_LEVEL +1> next{};`?

Comment: `new` in general is problematic, because it requires manual memory management. For single objects, you can feed the result to a shared pointer and are then on a much safer base. Better of course is the use of `make_shared` or `make_unique`. Now, for arrays, there is no such thing. Of course, you could pass it to `shared_ptr` with a custom deleter. Still, in practice, you are usually better off using `vector`.

Comment: In addition, concerning the code you linked: There, you have an array with a compile-time constant size. They used a regular array there, not `new[]`, so that's not comparable. Perhaps, they could benefit from using a `std::array` instead, which provides some STL-like container benefits without any runtime overheads.